# Event Listener doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So right now, I can dynamically create elements (2 rows of 12 blocks) and when I click on an individual block, I can change the color it as well.

However, I am having two main problems. When I click on the a block to have its color changed, the color picker will pop up beside it, no issues at all. But all the subsequent blocks that I click on, the color picker still pops up beside that first block that was clicked on.

I don't know why this is happening because I do bind the element that was clicked on to the color picker.

My second issue is a minor one but I am unsure of how to go about resolving it: the color picker sometimes appears behind the boxes.

Here is a link to what I have done so far:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwBRmw

```
var id_num = 1;
var picker = null;
$(function () {
$(document).on('click', ".repeat", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $self = $(this);
    var $parent = $self.parent();
    if($self.hasClass("add-bottom")){
      $parent.after($parent.clone(true).attr("id", "repeatable" + id_num));
      id_num = id_num + 1;
      //picker = null;

    } else {
      $parent.before($parent.clone(true).attr("id", "repeatable" + id_num));
      id_num = id_num + 1;
      //picker = null;
    }
});   
});


$(".container").on("click", "a", function(e) {
var self = this;
console.log(this.id)
console.log(this)
    if(!picker){
        console.log("new picker initialized")
        picker = new Picker(this)
    }
    else{
        console.log("gets inside else case")
        picker.settings = {
            parent: this,
            orientation: 'right',
            x: 'auto',
            y: 'auto',
            arrow_size: 20
        };

        //.parent = this;
    }
    picker.show();


 picker.on_done = function(colour) {
    $(self).css('background-color',colour.rgba().toString());
    picker.hide()
    }

e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: I would recommend finding a better documented color picker, like https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/

Comment: Looks like `show` method returns immediately after it has set an existing picker visible (see the lines 418 to 423). Hence all the settings are made only on the first call of `show` after the creation. Setting `picker` to `null` (currently commented out in your code) and creating a new Picker doesn't help, since it won't remove the wrapper element (`#picker_wrapper`) from the DOM, and `getElementById` always finds the firstly created element instead of new-ones (with the same `id`). Fixing these issues in the lib would be far too broad to answer.

Comment: @Teemu What would you recommend as an alternative? A new color picker?

Comment: Probably a new color picker would be the solution. After a small research, I found the original code from [GitHub](https://github.com/Dissimulate/Picker). The last commit has been on 12 Mar 2014, looks like the project is not active anymore. Another choice would be to fork the library, and fix the issues by yourself.